# Serializing object between Android and PC (Dalvik vs JVM)

Tags: android, serialization, jvm, dalvik, weka

I'm working with a large library, weka, and I'd like to transfer instances between the PC version and Android version.  I'd rather not have to rewrite the entire serialization between the two, but reguardless of what UID I change things to, I always get this error:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: [Lweka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron$NeuralEnd;; Incompatible class (SUID): [Lweka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron$NeuralEnd;: static final long serialVersionUID =-359311387972759020L; but expected [Lweka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron$NeuralEnd;: static final long serialVersionUID =1920571045915494592L;
```

It would appear the array itself has the wrong SUID, as those numbers don't match the number assigned to the class.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this eventually? I am having the same problem on Galaxy Nexus while it works on Nexus 5.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more code? It looks like a possible bug in the dalvikvm core libraries, which can be fixed if it is reported. Dalvik has a [public bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=label%3aComponent%20label%3aDalvik) for reviewing and reporting bugs.

Regardless of the bug, you should be able to work-around the problem by adding a [serialVersionUID](http://www.google.com/search?q=serialversionUID) field to your class.

Comment: this is in my code: 
`     protected class NeuralEnd extends NeuralConnection {
  
          /** for serialization */
          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
`
 so as you can see, I'm not defining the serialVersionUID that's showing up in the error.  My hunch is that the array uid is different.